# gnote: How to print a whole notebook

Tags: printing, notes

At present I'm working with [Gnote](https://help.gnome.org/users/gnote/unstable/). I know how to print a single *note*. Is there a way to print a whole *notebook* with ***several*** notes?

Or is there a recommended notebook to achieve this?

Any hint is welcome.

Answer (score 1):

Its documentation claims **if notes are linked** then you can output them all to HTML from the Tools menu, and print the HTML within the browser of your choice. This uses the preinstalled Add-in [Export to HTML](https://help.gnome.org/users/gnote/unstable/plugins.html.en).

An alternative is to install another Add-In, [Gnote to TXT exporter](https://github.com/rhoconlinux/gnote-massive-export-to-txt), or a use a script, [Gnote-massive-export-to-txt](https://github.com/rhoconlinux/gnote-massive-export-to-txt/blob/master/gnote-export-to-txt.sh), to export into text before printing.

Comment: Okay, I found out that I need to activate `export to HTML` and I did it. But this feature gives me just a html-file of one note and not the whole notebook. This is the same result like if I would print with `[ctrl]+[p]` into a `PDF`.

Comment: Were the notes linked?